# Github python script hanging: "WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified"

Tags: python, git, github, windowserror

I'm running a [python script](https://github.com/RockefellerArchiveCenter/asExportIncremental/blob/master/asExportIncremental.py) that exports xml from a database, converts the record to PDF, then attempts to upload both the xml and pdf files to a github repository. The export and pdf conversion work fine, but the process then hangs and outputs the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "asExportIncremental.py", line 394, in <module>
main()
File "asExportIncremental.py", line 320, in main
gitPush()
File "asExportIncremental.py", line 308, in gitPush
repo.push()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gittle\gittle.py", line 343, in push
return self.push_to(origin_uri, branch_name, progress)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gittle\gittle.py", line 338, in push_to
progress=progress
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\dulwich\client.py", line 440, in send_pack
proto, unused_can_read = self._connect('receive-pack', path)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\dulwich\client.py", line 893, in _connect
port=self.port, username=self.username)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\dulwich\client.py", line 758, in run_command
stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 390, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 640, in _execute_child
startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

My problem is that I'm not exactly sure where the script is failing. To which file is "WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified" referring? How do I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Probably *gittle* is a *git* wrapper, and it tries to call it, but it's unable to find it?

Comment: Use `print` statements in your script to print out paths of files/scripts you are using in your code to debug the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script calls gittle (high-level python git library) which executes dulwich (low-level python git wrapper) which [runs ssh](https://github.com/jelmer/dulwich/blob/master/dulwich/client.py#L1096) and fails. It seems `ssh.exe` is not in your PATH.

Comment: This was it! Thank you!